# Counting template recursion nest depth

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, sfinae

The following sequence applies to recursion to operate on a specific
nest level in a nested template object in held in a data parallel container 
class. I lifted out of an expression template engine I'm using where I might
want to, for example, transpose one index of a container of multi-dimensional
arrays.

I believe the code is unambiguous under SFINAE;

Containers go to third occurrence of function, failing to match "NestLevel". "Recursive" recurses through the second occurrence of function, until the Nest Level matches and it the recursion terminates on the first occurrence of function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::complex<double> ComplexD;

template <class T> class TypeMapper {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = T::NestLevel };
};

template<> class TypeMapper<ComplexD> {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = 0 };
};

template<class obj> class Container {
 public:
  std::vector<obj> data;
  Container(int size) : data (size){};
};

template<class obj> class Recursive {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = TypeMapper<obj>::NestLevel + 1};
  obj internal;
};

template<int N,class obj,typename std::enable_if<N==obj::NestLevel >::type * = nullptr > auto function(const obj &arg)-> obj
{
  std::cout<<"Leaf "<<obj::NestLevel<<std::endl;
  return arg;
}
template<int N,class obj,typename std::enable_if<N!=obj::NestLevel >::type * = nullptr > auto function(const obj &arg)-> obj
{
  std::cout<<"Node "<<obj::NestLevel<<std::endl;
  obj ret;
  ret.internal=function<N>(arg.internal);
  return ret;
}

template<int N,class obj> auto function(const Container<obj> & arg)-> Container<decltype(function<N>(arg.data[0]))>
{
  Container<decltype(function<N>(arg.data[0]))> ret(arg.data.size());
  for(int ss=0;ss<arg.data.size();ss++){
    ret.data[ss] = function<N>(arg.data[ss]);
  }
  return ret;
}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  Container<Recursive<Recursive<ComplexD> > > array(10);
  Container<Recursive<Recursive<ComplexD> > > ret(10);

  ret = function<1>(array);
}
```

It works on Intel 15, Clang++ multiple versions delivering what I expect.

```
pab$ icpc -std=c++11 broken.cc -o broken
pab$ clang++  -std=c++11 broken.cc -o broken
pab$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix

pab$ icpc --version
icpc (ICC) 15.0.3 20150408
Copyright (C) 1985-2015 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

With the output I expect:

```
pab$ ./broken 
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
Node 2
Leaf 1
```

Then

```
function(const Container<obj> & arg)
```

loops over the container, calling the

```
std::enable_if<N!=obj::NestLevel > function
```

this recurses, decrementing the nest level enum and then matches on the

```
std::enable_if<N==obj::NestLevel > function.
```

However, GCC fails to parse this, instead having function(Container) self call in an infinite recursive loop (4.8, 4.9) and with internal compiler error
on 5.0.

```
pab$ g++-5 -std=c++11 broken.cc -o broken
'
Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered.

broken.cc: In substitution of 'template<int N, class obj> Container<decltype (function<N>(arg.data[0]))> function(const Container<obj>&) [with int N = 1; obj = <missing>]':
broken.cc:43:101:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<int N, class obj> Container<decltype (function<N>(arg.data[0]))> function(const Container<obj>&) [with int N = 1; obj = <missing>]'
broken.cc:43:101:   required by substitution of 'template<int N, class obj> Container<decltype (function<N>(arg.data[0]))> function(const Container<obj>&) [with int N = 1; obj = <missing>]'
broken.cc:45:33:   Abort trap: 6
 template<int N,class obj> auto function(const Container<obj> & arg)-> Container<decltype(function<N>(arg.data[0]))>
                                                                                                     ^
g++-5: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues> for instructions.`enter code here`
```

The match looks buggy because function(const Container & arg) shouldn't
be recursing to itself because the parameters don't match. It should instead
substitution fail and call the other template for function. If I rename
these and change the call inside the Container parameter function it compiles.

Templates are hard though -- Is my programme legal and this a compiler bug?

UPDATE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::complex<double> ComplexD;

template <class T> class TypeMapper {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = T::NestLevel };
};

template<> class TypeMapper<ComplexD> {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = 0 };
};

template<class obj> class Container {
 public:
  std::vector<obj> data;
  Container(int size) : data (size){};
};

template<class obj> class Recursive {
public:
  enum { NestLevel = TypeMapper<obj>::NestLevel + 1};
  obj internal;
};

template<int N,class obj,typename std::enable_if<N==obj::NestLevel >::type * = nullptr > auto function(const obj &arg)-> obj
{
  std::cout<<"Leaf "<<obj::NestLevel<<std::endl;
  return arg;
}
template<int N,class obj,typename std::enable_if<N!=obj::NestLevel >::type * = nullptr > auto function(const obj &arg)-> obj
{
  std::cout<<"Node "<<obj::NestLevel<<std::endl;
  obj ret;
  ret.internal=function<N>(arg.internal);
  return ret;
}

template<int N,class obj> auto ffunction(const Container<obj> & arg)-> Container<decltype(function<N>(arg.data[0]))>
{
  Container<decltype(function<N>(arg.data[0]))> ret(arg.data.size());
  for(int ss=0;ss<arg.data.size();ss++){
    ret.data[ss] = function<N>(arg.data[ss]);
  }
  return ret;
}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  Container<Recursive<Recursive<ComplexD> > > array(10);
  Container<Recursive<Recursive<ComplexD> > > ret(10);

  ret = ffunction<1>(array);
}
```

This rename "function" to "ffunction" disambiguates the third from the first two occurrences and then G++ produces the right output because it doesn't (wrongly) recurse back into the function(container).

Appears to affect all versions of g++.

Comment: ICEs in [HEAD](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eK2AVfZXXss0ZDu6), works in 4.9. Seems like a regression in 5.

Comment: Thanks Columbo, I filed this and hope I get some traction.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66153               but I didn't get success on 4.9. where it wrongly recursed and hit a broken.cc:45:45:   template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900

Comment: That website is wonderful, thanks. I've been locally installing each compiler version by hand to now. But no version of GCC ever compiles it, with different errors on each. All versions of Clang++ after 3.1 succeed.

Comment: used your website to update the original.